# Iterate through memaligned pointer in C++

Tags: android, c++, audio, android-ndk

for an Android Sequencer App, we gave a try to the [Superpowered](http://superpowered.com) audio engine, which uses the Android NDK and C++. It's a very young project and there are some bugs in it, for example if a sample is too short, the buffers aren't cleared correctly, so I like to clear them by myself. For these, the memory is aligned this way:

```
bufferA = (float *)memalign(16, (buffersize + 16) * sizeof(float) * 2);
```

Because I'm a C++ beginner, I don't know how I could iterate through this pointer bufferA to overwrite its values.

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: I may have misunderstood your problem, but wouldn't a for loop be adequate? For example:
`for (int i = 0; i < buffersize; i++) bufferA[i] = something();`

Comment: `memset` would be faster: `memset(bufferA, 0, buffersize);`

Comment: @Buddy Oh, sure. I just assumed that we also need to give different values for each sample.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I just had to change "buffersize" to "(buffersize +16) * sizeof(float) *2". Maybe you meant that. Didnt know that its such as  easy to work with pointer array! Great!

Comment: @dasteini Would you be so kind as to point out -- specifically -- what you perceive as bugs? Thanks!